# Do distinct idempotent measures on finite binary systems have distinct supports?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, lo.logic, pr.probability

Suppose that $(S,*)$ is a finite set equipped with a binary operation.  Extend the binary operation to the vector space $V$ with basis $S$.
The set of probability measures on $S$, viewed as a compact convex subset of $V$ is closed under $*$
and, since $*$ is continuous, there are idempotent measures on $S$.

Must two idempotent measures on $S$ have distinct supports?

I am also interested in the more general question where the assumption of finiteness is dropped and one considers the extension (by convolution) of $*$ to the family of all finitely additive measures on $S$ (in that context, define the support of a measure to be all subsets of $S$ with positive measure).

Comment: Here "binary operation" on $S$ can be just any map $S\times S\rightarrow S$, or special properties are assumed?

Comment: Any operation.  *Nothing* is assumed.

Comment: If (S,*) is a group, then the idempotent measures are exactly the uniform measures on the subgroups of S. 

Comment: It is false for semigroups. The idempotent measures are obtained as follows. Take a regular J-class, a measure on its set of L-classes, a measure on its set of R-classes and uniform measure on its maximal subgroup. The corresponding product measure on the J-class is idempotent and they all look like this for compact topological semigroups. 

Comment: I meant above uniform measure on a subgp of a max subgp. 

Comment: I understand that the definition of $\mu*\nu$ is the push-forward of the product measure $\mu\otimes\nu$ on $S\times S$ via the map $ *:S\times S \rightarrow S$. But then, for instance if $*:S\times S \rightarrow S$ is  the projection on the first factor, isn't any probability measure on $S$ idempotent, just because $\mu*\nu=\mu$ holds for measures too?

Comment: Pietro, that is the content of my answer. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No if I understood. Take the two element left zero semigroup. All measures are idempotent.

**Added** a left zero semigroup is one satisfying the identity xy=x

**Added** A finite semigroup $S$ satisfies that distinct idempotent measures have distinct support iff for all idempotents $e,f\in S$ one has $SeS=SfS$ implies $e=f$.

A finite semigroup has a unique idempotent measure with full support iff it is a finite group.

Here is how the proof goes. Suppose $P$ is an idempotent measure on $S$ and assume the support of $P$ is $S$.

Claim 1: $S$ contains no ideal.

Proof.  Obviously every state is recurrent for both the right random walk an left random walk on $S$ driven by $P$ because $P$ is idempotent and the support is $S$ (and hence $P$ is stationary for these walks).  If $I$ was a proper ideal, then the states in $S\setminus I$ would have to be transient because they fall into $I$ with positive probability.  Thus $S$ has no proper ideals.

By Rees's theorem, if $e$ is an idempotent of $S$ then $eSe$ is a group $G$, there are sets $A$ and $B$, and a mapping $P\colon B\times A\to G$ such that $S\cong A\times G\times B$ with multiplication $$(a,g,b)(a',b',b') = (a,gP(b,a')g',b).$$

It is trivial to check that if $Q$ is a measure on $A$, $U$ is uniform measure on $G$ and $R$ is a measure on $B$, then $Q\times U\times R$ is an idempotent measure on $S$.  The fact that all idempotent measures $A\times G\times B$ are of this form is an easy calculation using  that the only idempotent measure on a finite group with global support is the uniform measure.    The key point is to first show that the measure is uniform on subsets of the form $\{a\}\times G\times \{b\}$ using the group result.

Comment: In general if a finite semigroup has a regular J-class which is not a group then it has distinct idempotent measures with the same support. 

Comment: Of course they all are, unless your product is not the usual one.  Suppose x,y are the two elements and p+q=1 with p,q\geq 0.  Then 
$(px+qy)(px+qy) = p^2x+pqx+qpy+q^2y=p(p+q)x+q(p+q)y = px+qy$.

Comment: Here is a reference for the characterization of idempotent measures on compact semigroups

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1963-014-01/S0002-9939-1963-0169971-2/home.html

There is a generalization by John Pym for compact semitopological semigroups.  

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right.  I deleted my comment.

Comment: It is amusing that groups are the only finite semigroups which admit a unique idempotent probability measure with global support.